# How can I forward calls from a Twilio or Nexmo number I bought to my Android phone over data / VOIP?

Tags: android, twilio, voip, vonage

I don't want to forward to my mobile number, I want to install some kind of "softphone" and have Twilio / Nexmo forward the call to that softphone. Can my Android phone receive VOIP calls directly somehow?

This seems like such a simple thing to do, but I can't figure out how to do it. Do I need my own "SIP trunk"? Surely not, for such a simple use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do this using an Android SIP soft phone (see [this post for some recommendations](https://www.lifewire.com/apps-for-sip-on-android-3426471)) and [Twilio's SIP Registration](https://www.twilio.com/voice/sip-registration). Check out the gif below for how to set up SIP registration for incoming calls to a soft phone:

[image]

The steps are:

- Create a [SIP domain in the Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/sip/endpoints)
- Create a [Credential List](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/sip/cls) with at least one username and password
- Enable SIP registration for the SIP domain using the credential list you created
- Configure your SIP Phone application

  - User the username and password you chose for your credential list
  - Make sure the soft phone registers successfully
- Buy a number
- Configure a TwiML Bin to [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) to your [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip) address on incoming calls
- Dial that number and your soft phone should ring

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks. This is working for me. Do you have a recommendation for an Android softphone? Just for taking personal calls forwarded from Twilio. I'm using Sipdroid. It's OK

Comment: I don't use an Android, so I don't know personally. I've heard good things about Bria though. Also, if this is working, would you mind marking it as the right answer so that others can see it helped too? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I've marked your answer as correct. Does Twilio have an easy-to-configure voicemail service? Using the config you've suggested, I'd like to receive an email with the voicemail recording if I miss a call.

Comment: The [Twimlets voicemail](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/voicemail) app is a pretty easy way to set that up.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get that to work. Could you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44767139/how-can-i-make-an-outgoing-phone-call-from-a-soft-phone-sipdroid-using-twilio

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to forward to your personal number, you can buy some Virtual number from Application like [Vyke](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vyke.vtl), [RWG](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rwgmobile.vtl). and give that number it will reach your app in your mobile.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid routing over the PSTN twice: the incoming call will go over the PSTN to Twilio, and then Twilio will route it over the PSTN to Vyke or similar. I find the call quality is quite bad in these cases, and I'm assume it's because of the double PSTN routing.