# How can I make an outgoing phone call from a soft phone (Sipdroid) using Twilio?

Tags: twilio

I've set up a SIP domain, so I can forward calls from numbers I bought with Twilio to my soft phone.

But I also want to make outgoing calls to PSTN numbers from the soft phone. How can I do this? I suspect it involves an Elastic SIP Trunk, but I can't figure out how to configure it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it using the PHP helper library without elastic trunking.

In the SIP domains settings on your Twilio console you can set a request URL for voice configuration. It seems that when you try to make an outgoing call to any number via SIP then Twilio requests this URL and POSTs all the call info variables with the request. One of the variables is 'Called' which takes the format sip:0123456789@yourdomain.sip.us1.twilio.com:5060 where 0123456789 is the number you have dialled

So all we need to do is strip the number out of the string and then ask Twilio to dial it. Easy enough.

I created this php file, I'm in the UK so it formats the number to call with the UK country code .You will have to change it a bit for other countries.

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Twiml;
$calledNo = explode("@", $_POST['Called']); // Splits sip:0123456789@yourdomain.sip.us1.twilio.com:5060 into an array at the @ character
$callthis = '+44'.substr($calledNo[0], 5); // $calledNo[0] is set to sip:0123456789, this line strips the first 5 characters leaving 123456789 and adds +44 to the start (UK country code)
$response = new Twiml();
$dial = $response->dial(['callerId' => '{Your caller id}']); // Your caller ID must be validated or the outgoing call will fail
$dial->number($callthis); // Calls +44123456789

echo $response;
```

Point your voice URL at this file and you're all set.

Comment: Hey miknik, Thanks for all the help you're lending to the Stack Overflow community. Would love to send you something to say thanks from Twilio. If that sounds cool to you email mspeir at twilio dot com. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an AWS Lambda which does the same as miknik's PHP:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ses = new aws.SES({
   region: 'us-east-1'
});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

    console.log("Event: ", event);

    var called = event.queryStringParameters.Called;

    var number = called.match(/:(.*)@/)[1];

    console.log("Number is [" + number + "]");

    var dialCommand = '<Dial callerId="...">'
        + number
        + '</Dial>';

    callback(null, { 

        statusCode: 200, 
        body: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response>' + dialCommand + '</Response>',

        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
        }

    });

};
```

Set the "REQUEST URL" under "Voice Configuration" for your SIP Domain to "HTTP GET" in Twilio